# Can search engines track # in your site?

Tags: html, seo, fragment-identifier

I have created one paged site and it has a lot of `<div>` blocks with unique IDs. When I click links that has reference to these IDs my borwsers address line will show this:

```
my.example.com/index.html#my_id
```

Do search engines detect this?

Comment: `#` is a mark for a [fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). A fragment is used to start the page at different locations in the browser window. Fragments are indexed as the same resource than the URL without fragment. However Google uses a special *hash bang* (`#!`) to circumvent this problem. See: [Hash Symbols in URLs and SEO](https://www.oho.com/blog/explained-60-seconds-hash-symbols-urls-and-seo)

Comment: so I need to add to my href this `<a href="#!my_id" ></a>` or `<div id="!my_id">` ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I wanted my `<div>` elements with ids trackable on search engines.